# Unable view messages in SQS resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-cloudformation

I created SQS and SNS resources by using a CloudFormation template, Jenkins, and added subscription to SNS. When it is subscribed to an SNS topic, it should be getting messages pushed each time a topic is published with a new message, but the problem is I am unable to view that messages in SQS (Messages available 0). And when I am using AWS CLI it is working fine.

While trying to receive the messages, the following error is thrown:

> Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to Amazon SQS, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.
>   Error Message: The ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access. (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 36a6b851-aed5-4e0c-ae77-a8c21c9931df) (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: KMS.AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 07f77a5b-b72e-5361-9353-2e24fd5db4e1)
>   HTTP Status Code: 400
>   AWS Error Code: KMS.AccessDeniedException
>   Error Type: Client
>   Request ID: 07f77a5b-b72e-5361-9353-2e24fd5db4e1

While sending the messages, the following error is thrown (Sending a message to MyQueue):

> Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to Amazon SQS, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.
>   Error Message: User: arn:aws:sts::230529650436:assumed-role/Vz-SAML-OnShoreDeveloper_R/kanchana.rajaram@verizonwireless.com is not authorized to perform: kms:GenerateDataKey on resource: arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:230529650436:key/5b0d3035-5c23-4077-b516-cdb7c763be6a (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 7bef5363-c010-48d1-9fa1-93a50cb020d0) (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: KMS.AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 73a56dc4-86d8-5e3a-aed7-39bbcdd52c66)
>   HTTP Status Code: 400
>   AWS Error Code: KMS.AccessDeniedException
>   Error Type: Client
>   Request ID: 73a56dc4-86d8-5e3a-aed7-39bbcdd52c66

FYI:

- https://onejenkinscloud.vpc.verizon.com/vzw/view/VZW.GZ8V/job/VZW.GZ8V.Enforce.Jobs/job/VZW.GZ8V.Credit-Alarm.Infrastructure.Jobs/job/VZW.GZ8V.Credit-Event-SQS.Nonprod/
- SNS - VZ-GZ8V-CreditEvent-SNS-Nonprod
- SQS - VZ-GZ8V-CreditEvent-SQS-Nonprod-SQSQueue-1LWVWF580G04J

Answer (score 0):

The first error suggests that you are referring to a KMS key that does not exist.

The second error says that your code (or something it is triggering) is trying to use the `kms:GenerateDataKey` API call, but you are not authorized to make this call.

Both errors relate to KMS, so it seems that your queue might be encrypted but you do not have adequate permissions to decrypt the messages.